# How to set correct Content-Type HTTP header for all files uploaded on S3 bucket?

Tags: amazon-s3, cloudflare, cdn

What is please the correct way to set `Content-Type` HTTP header for files uploaded on S3 bucket? We use S3 bucket as an origin server for hosting static websites. Bucket is accessed through the Cloudflare CDN.

After copying the files, the `Content-Type` by default is set to `binary/octet-stream`.

- Of course, I can set it up when copying via the AWS CLI for individual files, but even with reasonable automation, it's extra work, and then, in addition to `.js`, `.html`, `.css`, there are also a number of `images`, `fonts`, `videos`, `json` files, etc. It seems pointless to me to set the correct content type for each file type.
- I can also set it up with rules on the CDN, but again that's per file type.

Is it not possible to instruct the S3 bucket so that it automatically sets the `Content-Type` in a similar way as web servers like nginx or Apache do?

Answer (score 0):

I figured out that there is no problem and it was all caused by the way the MAC OS version of the [CloudBerry](https://www.msp360.com/explorer/mac/) - GUI software we have used to copy files to S3 bucket.

CloudBerry enforced the `binary/octet-stream` content type when files were copied to S3 (I am not sure why, it might be some setting/option - I have not explored that further). Switching to AWS CLI and overwriting all files fixed the problem.